# healpy ang2pix:planckerror

Tags: python

I am trying to convert CATALOG.FIT into healpix fits image. I am able to read fits catalog and convert ra and dec into theta and phi. But when I use ang2pix, it throws an error"

```
 Error encountered at /home/faisal/healpy/healpy-healpy-aa5f605/hpbeta  
 /Healpix_cxx/healpix_base.cc, line 829
 (function I T_Healpix_Base<I>::loc2pix(double, double, double, bool) const [with I = 
 long int])
```

must not happen

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'PlanckError'
Abort

```
-------------------
import numpy as np

import string as s

from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import healpy as hp

from numpy import sin, cos, arccos, arcsin, arctan2

import astro_util as au


#start healpy---------------------------



nvss_ra=np.arange(1,100,1) 

nvss_dec=np.arange(1,100,1)

print nvss_ra

theta,phi= au.euler(nvss_ra,nvss_dec,1)

print theta

theta1=theta/(57.3248)

phi1=phi/(57.3248)+((3.14159265359)/2)

nvssmap=np.zeros(hp.nside2npix(512))

#Working till this point

pix=hp.pixelfunc.ang2pix(512,theta1, phi1)




nvssmap[pix]=1

hp.fitsfunc.write_map("nvss_map.fits",nvssmap)
```

---

Please reply if someone also faced the similar problem.

Thanks

Faisal

Comment: where can I download astro_util? or can you make an example that does not use it?

Comment: astro_util is available at:
source: http://sdss.physics.nyu.edu/esheldon/python/code/astro_code-2009-05-15/astro_util.py


instead of using euler, you can use :
pix = healpy.ang2pix(512, np.radians(90-nvss_dec, np.radians(nvss_ra))
It may not be exact conversion but it may be good enough to test ang2pix.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, `theta` is defined between 0 and pi, if you give `ang2pix` a negative value, it fails with that error.

I will add a more meaningful error message to the healpy source code.

Comment: Hi

The issue is resolved. It was more related to the theta and phi convention. The ang2pix function theta, phi parameters were following opposite convention of longitude and latitude to the convention I was following :)
I checked the euler code in the library and then checked ang2pix to realize what the problem is.
Thanks 

Faisal